# Draw an anti aliased rounded rectangle in c++

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, sdl, antialiasing

As written in the title, i would like to draw anti aliased rounded rectangles in c++ and in a linux context (ubuntu). I already tried SDL_gfx but anti aliasing is not available on roundedBox shapes. I also read about SDL_Draw but I think it does neither provide anti aliasing.

That's why I am asking if anybody knows a framework providing this kind of shapes or if anybody knows a (light) anti aliasing algorithm (I need this for real time video processing).

---

Thank you Vjo, but I don't really want to use openGL in my soft ... And by the way, I think I figured out another way to draw anti aliased rounded rectangles !

What I did not explain in the first post is that i am already using SDL and opencv in my program. So I had an idea :

- draw a 1 channel rounded rectangle with SDL_gfx
- smooth it with cvSmooth to get the antialiasing alpha
- use the result as the alpha channel of a simple rectangle

What do you think about that ? I'll try it this evening !

Comment: It worked but is still a bit ugly.

Answer (score 0):

The only parts of the shape that need to be antialiased are the corners.  draw four antialiased quater circles, one at each corner (Xiaolin Wu's circle algrithm is your best bet here), and bridge the gaps with simple lines.  If the shapes will not be rotated (that is, all straight lines will be either vertical or horizontal, use Bresenham's non-antialiased line algorithm, otherwise use Wu's line algorithm.  Wu's antialiasing algorithms are typically the fastest and give very good results.

If you really want to optimize your result, and are familiar with x86 assembly programming, I suggest writing the drawing routines using inline assembly language.  Properly tuned, wu's line algorithm can be written in as few as 15 instructions, and his circle algorithm around 40-50 instructions.